# Creating a loop that calculates the weighted spread for ask and bid on a roundtrip of 800

Tags: r

I am a beginner at R (less than 2 years experience) and have been searching in the forums for an answer to my question.

I have a financial stock dataset similar to the following:

| sign | reference | price | total_volume | type | PM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80407_34260 | 16.78 | 100 | bid | 16.81 |
| 2 | 80407_34260 | 16.77 | 500 | bid | 16.81 |
| 3 | 80407_34260 | 16.75 | 1064 | bid | 16.81 |
| -1 | 80407_34260 | 16.84 | 200 | ask | 16.81 |
| -2 | 80407_34260 | 16.85 | 255 | ask | 16.81 |
| -3 | 80407_34260 | 16.89 | 2200 | ask | 16.81 |
| 1 | 80407_34320 | 16.76 | 185 | bid | 16.795 |
| 2 | 80407_34320 | 16.75 | 1064 | bid | 16.795 |
| 3 | 80407_34320 | 16.74 | 100 | bid | 16.795 |
| -1 | 80407_34320 | 16.83 | 100 | ask | 16.795 |
| -2 | 80407_34320 | 16.84 | 1800 | ask | 16.795 |
| -3 | 80407_34320 | 16.85 | 100 | ask | 16.795 |

Where PM is the midpoint.

I need to calculate the weighted relative spread for each reference for a roundtrip of 800 and 100.

The weighted spread is calculated as the difference between the wighted ask spread and the weighted bid spread onto the roundtrip.

A manual example for reference 80407_34260 in the 100 roundtrip would be:

-> S_A(100) = (100*16.85)/100 = 16.85

-> S_B(100) = (100*16.78)/100 = 16.78

And for the 800 roundtrip:

-> S_A(800) = (200*16.84+255*16.85+(800-255-200)*16.89)/800

-> S_B(800) = (100*16.78+500*16.77+(1064-500-100)*16.75)/800

So to weigh you have to multiply the total_volume * quote as long as it covers the roundtrip volume.

The relative spread would then be S_A(800) - S_B(800)/PM

So my trouble is that I have to create a function that contains a loop that goes through each reference and calculates both S_A and S_B for the concrete roundtrip. I want 2 columns, one for S_A and one for S_B per reference. I am not sure on how to create this and additionally, the thing is that references have different quantities of rows.

I also have the premise that if the sum of total_volumes for a reference is < roundtrip the full reference (and all its associated rows) should be deleted.

Maybe I need to create a counter for this?

I had thought of something like this:

```
vol_function = function(Stock, roundtrip, start, end){   totalcounter = 0
price = 0
for (i in start:end){
if(totalcounter < roundtrip){ 
   if(totalcounter + Stock$total_volume[i] > roundtrip){ 
      currentcounter = roundtrip - totalcounter}
   else{currentcounter = Stock$total_volume[i]}
price = price + (currentcounter * Stock$quote[i])
totalcounter = totalcounter + currentcounter}
}
return(price)}
```

And then:

```
get_results = function(stock){
start = 1
end = 10
data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 11, nrow = 0))
names <- c("Day","Hour", "Bid100", "Ask100", "Spread100",
           "Bid800", "Ask800", "Spread800")
colnames(data) <- names
while(end < nrow(stock)){
 bid100 = vol_function(stock, 100, start, end)
 bid800 = vol_function(stock, 800, start, end)     
 start = start + 10
 end = end+ 10
 ask100 = vol_function(stock, 100, start, end)     
 ask800 = vol_function(stock, 800, start, end) 
 data = data %>% add_row(Day= stock$date[start], 
                         Hour = stock$time[start],
                         Bid100 = bid100,
                         Ask100 = ask100,
                         spread100 = ask100 - bid100,
                         Bid800 = bid800,
                         Ask800 = ask800,
                         spread800 = ask800 - bid800)                       
 start = start + 10
 end = end + 10}   
 return(data)}
```

Comment: These are useful bits to put into your question rather than as comments.  What, in your context, is "a roundtrip of 800 and 100"?

Comment: Is your formula right for the 800 S_B? It seems like your weighted calc uses 100 + 500 + (1064 - 500 - 100) = 1064 shares where I think you wanted 800.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have updated the formula I already thought in my head. The roundtrip would be the number of stock to weigh the spread and bid. To thing like the comparison volume.

Comment: In my formula, I am moving to the next reference by adding a + 10, which is a false assumption, since there are references which have more or less rows. I'd like to move to the following reference instead, but I am not sure on how to add it to the start and end points.

Comment: Just as a comment, it is a +10 since the original data has indeed usually 10 ask rows and 10 bid rows per reference. But I want to avoid relying on the +10 and instead would like to refer to the reference column that I created on purpose

Comment: Also, I am not sure if I was clear enough but the spread(100) or spread(800) should be the same for all rows in a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you're looking for.

It's a function that takes the data frame, groups it by reference and type (so subsequent calculations will be within those groups), calculates how much volume there was in prior observations, figures out how much of the current row should be included to get up to but no higher than the roundtrip total, and then multiplies that by the current price.

The last part is to summarize the total amount paid divided by roundtrip.  `moar_digits` shows more digits, since the default printing will make all the prices in the example look like 16.8 or 16.9.

If you want, this could be further reshaped (e.g. with `tidyr::pivot_wider`) to put the ask and bid in a single row.

```
library(dplyr)
calc_roundtrip <- function(roundtrip) {
  df %>%
    group_by(reference, type) %>%
    mutate(prior_cuml_vol  = cumsum(lag(total_volume, default = 0)),
           cur_incl =  pmax(0,pmin(total_volume, (roundtrip - prior_cuml_vol))),
           paid = cur_incl * price) %>%
    summarize(total = sum(paid) / roundtrip) %>%
    mutate(moar_digits = formatC(total, digits = 6)) %>%
    mutate(spread = total - lag(total))
}

calc_roundtrip(800)


#`summarise()` has grouped output by 'reference'. You can override using the `.groups`
#argument.
## A tibble: 4 × 5
## Groups:   reference [2]
#  reference   type  total moar_digits  spread
#  <chr>       <chr> <dbl> <chr>         <dbl>
#1 80407_34260 ask    16.9 16.8648     NA     
#2 80407_34260 bid    16.8 16.7662     -0.0985
#3 80407_34320 ask    16.8 16.8388     NA     
#4 80407_34320 bid    16.8 16.7523     -0.0864
```

Comment: Jon! That is exactly what I needed! The group by reference is helping me avoid the different rows ! Thank you so much!